# How to enable php error display in shopware 6?

Tags: shopware

How to enable php error display in shopware 6?

I got the following message when php error occurs but not showing the php error?

> Unfortunately, something went wrong.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66693754/getting-oops-an-error-occurred-with-no-logs-beeing-written-on-shopware-6-3-5-2/66693755#66693755

Answer (score 0):

this should be possible, if you set the `APP_ENV` config in the `.env` file to `dev`

Best regards from Schöppingen

Michael Telgmann

Comment: This does not work for me (Shopware 6.3). It just shows 'Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error"'. There are no log entries in the server logs. I tracked this page down, it's a twig template.