# Getting "oops an error occurred" with no logs beeing written on Shopware 6.3.5.2

Tags: debugging, shopware

I am getting this error after installation on a docker setup, no logs are being written. How can I debug this issue further?

Comment: Since this is a symfony error: https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/186

Answer (score 1):

If APP_DEBUG and APP_ENV=dev does not help, you can forcefully edit
`vendor/symfony/error-handler/ErrorRenderer/HtmlErrorRenderer.php`

and add $debug=true;

```
public function __construct($debug = false, string $charset = null, $fileLinkFormat = null, string $projectDir = null, $outputBuffer = '', LoggerInterface $logger = null)
{
     $debug = true;  #add this line
```